# SQL Loader in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

As I am inserting data from a `CSV file` to a oracle table using `SQL Loader` and it is working fine .

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE DataOut.txt
BADFILE dataFile.bad
APPEND INTO TABLE ASP_Net_C_SHARP_Articles
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
(ID,Name,Category)
```

above settings are being used to do that but I do not want to specify any of the  column name `ex. (ID,Name,Category)` .

Is this possible or not if yes can anybody tell me how..

Comment: no.. I do not think that is possible. is there some reason for not wanting to put in the column names?

Answer (score 0):

In `SQL*Loader` you need to specify the column names. If you still persist in ignoring the column names in the control file, then I would suggest you to use SQL to "discover" the name of the columns and dynamically generate the control file and wrap it via shell script to make it more automated.

Meanwhile, you can consider External Tables which uses the `SQL*Loader` engine, so you will still have to perform some dynamic creation here for your input file as suggested above. But you can create a script to scan the input file and dynamically generate the `CREATE TABLE..ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL` command for you. Then the data becomes available as if it were a table in your database.

You can also partially skip the columns if that would help you, by using `FILLER`. `BOUNDFILLER` (available with Oracle 9i and above) can be used if the skipped column's value will be required later again.